# Cracking the Coding Interview 1.1

Tags: python, arrays, string

The problem asks us to implement a function called “isUnique” which will return True or False as to whether a string contains all unique characters.

One approach is to use a Boolean array while the other uses a HashTable.

In Python we get this for the Boolean array:

```
def is_unique(str):
    # Assuming character set is ASCII (128 characters)
    if len(string) > 128:
        return False

    char_set = [False] * 128

    for char in string:
        val = ord(char)

        if char_set[val]:
            return False

        char_set[val] = True

    return True
```

And this using a dictionary/hash map:

```
def is_unique(str):
    # Assuming character set is ASCII (128 characters)
    if len(string) > 128:
        return False

    character_counts = {}

    for char in string:
        if char in character_counts:
            return False

        character_counts[char] = 1

    return True
```

Personally I find the dictionary approach to be more intuitive, but the book gives the former solution along with a bitwise approach.

So, is there any sense in using one over the other if it came up in an interview, or perhaps it’s just useful to talk about the different options available. Although, I still don’t know how much discernment can be made between the two.

Edit: To be clear, I’m just wondering if there are any noticeable pro’s and con’s between using the Boolean array versus a hash map. Or are they essentially identical given any situation?

Comment: An easier method, it seems to me, is the one line `return len(str) == len(set(str))`.  That's essentially a degenerate case of the dictionary solution.

Comment: That comes up on the solutions [page](https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition-Python/blob/master/chapter_01/p01_is_unique.py). I guess I’m just wondering how identical the boolean approach is to the dictionary approach.

Comment: If the question is to solve this problem in Python, then Tim's solution is by far the most Pythonic (and fastest) one compared to the other solutions linked or shown here.

Comment: You could make all kinds of arguments here -- which is why this will likely be closed as off-topic. For example, you may argue that the boolean array approach is bad because it assumes a certain amount of possible unique characters, whereas the dictionary doesn't.

Comment: If you want to compare the two solutions listed in your question, you can start with timing them. Possibly of relatively little importance (and language / implementation dependent), but it's a starting point to see a difference (or not).

Comment: In terms of philosophy, the two snippets are virtually identical.  The boolean array will be faster, because array indexing is slightly faster than hash table tree traversal, but this is never going to be a performance-critical function.

Comment: I'm going to say that I prefer the hash table over the array index because it doesn't assume ASCII.  *I* moved away from this style of C programming when I went to python (as well as not caring so much about micro performance, since python is "50x slower than C").  Furthermore, the standard library, collections.Counter in this case, guarantees that you don't mess up your implementation and should be used over any "roll your own" solution.  I'm highly impressed by fiercely non-clever programming.

Comment: Why do both functions return `False` if the length of the string is more than 128 characters? If the string is `'x' * 1000` we still have only unique characters.